# Android TAB ui help

Tags: android

This is my code for my main, the main xml isnt being recognized.. I have done a clean. also my drawable folder isnt working. I made a folder in my res call "drawable" and added my xml of my drawable and my icons and it isnt finding it.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 // Drawable TestImage = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_test);
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("test").setIndicator("test",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_test))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestActivity2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("test2").setIndicator("test2",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TestActivity3.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("test3").setIndicator("test3",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
```

}

Here is my main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I cant seem to see what the error is caused from? help me please. I am just learning this

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to a lot of things. Normally, when you create an android project, the drawable folder is automatically created. Have you actually created a new Android project (vs a new java project)?

I copied and pasted your code, and it works for me. So I guess, create a new ANDROID project, and try again...

Also, to make sure we are on the same page, your drawables go in the drawable folder, and your layout (main.xml) should go in the layout folder

```
res\
    drawable\
       ic_images.png
    layout\
       main.xml
```

Comment: Entreco has explained properly. Try to clean your project before launching it.